# How to call method after completing method?

Tags: angular, typescript

Ok, i tried to change margin after hidden text in sidebar by using width of element, but it gets value before hiding text, how can i fix it?

TS

```
toggle_menu_text() {
    this.menu_bar_status = !this.menu_bar_status;
    this.change_margin();
  }
  change_margin() {
    this.side_bar_width = document.getElementById('side_nav_width').offsetWidth;
    console.log(this.side_bar_width);
  }
```

HTML

```
<mat-sidenav-content [style.margin-left.px] = "side_bar_width">
```

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73i3M.gif)

Comment: can you query offsetWidth after hiding?

Comment: Can you show how you use `menu_bar_status` in the HTML template?

Comment: <span [class.menu-bar]="menu_bar_status" class="ml-1">{{link.name}}</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow time for the changes in the component to be rendered to the DOM.

One way to do this is to use a `window.setTimeout()` to execute the `change_margin()` in the next JavaScript cycle.

```
toggle_menu_text() {
    this.menu_bar_status = !this.menu_bar_status;
    window.setTimeout(()=>this.change_margin());
}
```

The above will delay the call to the function, but now change detection won't work. So we must run the callback inside Angular using a zone. You can use a zone by injecting `NgZone` into your component's constructor and calling the `run()` method.

```
toggle_menu_text() {
    this.menu_bar_status = !this.menu_bar_status;
    window.setTimeout(()=> this.zone.run(()=>this.change_margin()));
}
```

**UPDATED:**

As pointed out in the comment. I do not believe you need to use zones with `setTimeout()`.

[When should i use zone.run in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065859/when-should-i-use-zone-run-in-angular-2)

Comment: Why zone doesn't work? I thought ZoneJS overrode setTimeout

Comment: @CristianTraìna I believe you are correct. Thank. I'll update the answer